# How to avoid weird drooping edges in `geom_density`

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, rstan

Both of these plots are of the same data series:

[image: with xlim(-10,10)]

[image: with xlim(-20,20)]

How can I get around the artefact seen here: namely, that the density line for the prior droops in the corners?

EDIT: to clarify, I'm using `geom_density` to compute the line. Some example code showing roughly what I'm doing is here, and which produces very similar (although not identical) plots.

https://gist.github.com/a00d1607ee39aac8dff94640b514fd53

I'm not asking how to compute a different posterior. In the examples shown, the only thing that changed was the `xlim` values. The data passed to `geom_density` was otherwise the same.

EDIT 2:

I've posted the data in `both` to here: https://gist.github.com/000b44cb340b3baac0d1eb313a42d78a as requested.

Thanks also for the suggestion to look at `trim` which made me think about how the plot was being drawn. Interestingly, if I used `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(20,40))` I get a very different result to just using `xlim(20,40)`. I think this means I hadn't really understood what `geom_density` and ggplot was doing under the hood though, so any explanation as to why these additional plots (again of the same data series) differ so much would be much appreciated. Is the problem that the plot using `xlim` is requiring each density to sum to 1 within the plot, where `coord_cartesian` effectively just crops/zooms the plot of the whole density?

No constraints on x axis:

[image: No constraints]

Constraining x axis using `xlim`:

[image: Constraining x axis using <code>xlim</code>]

Constraining x axis with `cood_cartesian`:

[image: Constraining x axis with <code>cood_cartesian</code>]

Comment: (1) Are you asking about how to redraw the graphic, how to compute a different posterior, or maybe something else?  Without some clarification and context this presently looks too ambiguous to answer. (2) In what sense are these of the "same data series," given that the prior density is so different in the second plot?  What are the characteristics of these data series and what algorithm did you use to compute the densities?

Comment: I can't share these data, but I'm just using geom_density to compete the density line. I will add some example code to the question

Comment: Have you tried using `trim = TRUE`? It'd help if you'd add the final dataset used for plotting (called `both` on your gist) to your question.  That way folks don't have to run models and manipulate data to look at the ggplot2 issue.